# Is a time based app possible using aws lambda?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an app where users send a JSON from their geographical location to the server, and server collects all requests from that location under 5 seconds from the first request sent from that location. I want to store all requests in a hashmap where key is the LocationKey and the value is the list of all requests from that location.  I'm having trouble modeling it in aws lambda since it's only api calls so coding a time based app is hard to conceptualize. Also I'm not sure where would I store the hashmap. I'm new to backend dev and any help would be much appreciated.

The app-server relation is as follows:

On User's Mobile:

1. Create a JSON with { LocationKey, username, otherinfo.. }.
2. Send that JSON to the server.

Server:

1. If LocationKey doesn't exist in the hashmap -> (1) Create a new hashmap value
   < Key: LocationKey, Value: < < Request1 > > >
   (2) Start Timer
2. If LocationKey exists in the hashmap and timer hasn't expired
       then add requests to the hashmap based on LocationKey
       < Key: LocationKey, Value: < < Request1 >, < Request2 > > >
3. If timer has ended

   (1)Return the hashmap value to each request in the hashmap

   (2)Delete the hashmap entry

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store the data somewhere outside of Lambda, and look it up each time Lambda is called. I think storing the data in DynamoDB would work well for your scenario.

Comment: Agreed. Each Lambda invocation could store data in DynamoDB, wait 5 seconds, read from DynamoDB and then return a response. Instead of conceptualising a "server", think of it as each user invoking an independent "task" that uses DynamoDB to communicate between tasks. Instead of deleting data from DynamoDB, simply ignore something that is older that the desired time, thereby eliminating a "cleanup" phase. Think scale!